# Are there good algorithms for finding sentences given only their sentence embedding?

Tags: natural-language, word2vec, word-embeddings

A common baseline that often works really well for sentence vectors is simply to average the word vectors for each word in the sentence. So lets say I have a vector made in this way. If I have a dictionary with lots of words and their associated word vectors, can I get the most likely sequence of words that made this sentence vector?

I'm fine with assuming we have 8 or less words in our sentence so unscrambling words is easy, but I'd like to have this algorithm work with millions of words in my dictionary.

Comment: You could train a recurrent neural network to do this.

Comment: @Aaron what do you mean?

Comment: Ohh do you mean just use the decoder part of a seq to seq rnn? That’s a good idea

Comment: Yeah I think that's your best option.